# Ace Editor - Clear Selection is not working

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I am using the ace-editor in my application. I'm overriding the default undo functionality. On click on Ctrl+z updated are reverting properly but ace-editor is not clearing selected value, it is still showing highlighted.

1. override undo.

   ```
   this.templateeditor.getEditor().commands.addCommand({
     name: 'annotateCommand',
     bindKey: { win: 'ctrl-z', mac: 'Command-z' },
     exec: (editor: any) => {
       this.handleUndo(this.modal);
     }
   });
   ```
2. handle undo.

   ```
   public handleUndo(modal) {
       this.templateeditor.getEditor().session.getUndoManager().undo();
       this.templateeditor.getEditor().getSelection().clearSelection();
   }
   ```

a) On load first time:
[image]

b) After updating value:
[image]

c) On undo:
[image]

Can someone please tell why `clearSelection()` is not working?

Comment: which version of ace do you use, this seems to work correctly on ace.c9.io

Comment: I am using "ng2-ace-editor": "0.2.0".

Comment: what is the version of ace itself, that is `ace.version` in browser console

Comment: it is **1.3.3**